# NUnit ITest "Properties" field: Is it settable by user?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

So I have setup this scenario:

```
private void InitializeTestProperties()
{
    SetTestPropertiesRecur(mTestRunner.Test, "Show", true);
    VerifyPropertiesRecur(mTestRunner.Test, "Show");
}
```

I am expecting all tests loaded into the "mTestRunner" to have the property "Show" stored in the dictionary provided by the ITest set to "true".

When this code is executed, the "Properties" field of the ITest seems to have the correct value set:

```
private void SetTestPropertiesRecur(ITest test, object key, object val)
{
    test.Properties[key] = val;
    Console.WriteLine(test.TestName.FullName + ": " + test.Properties[key]); // works
    if (test.IsSuite)
    {
        foreach (ITest child in test.Tests)
        {
            SetTestPropertiesRecur(child, key, val);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to verify through another function, the "Properties" field is not set again.

```
private void VerifyPropertiesRecur(ITest test, object key)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.TestName.FullName + ": " + test.Properties[key]); // does not print the right value. "test.Properties[key]" has nothing associated with it for all tests.
    if (test.IsSuite)
    {
        foreach (ITest child in test.Tests)
        {
            VerifyProperties(child, key);
        }
    }
}
```

In summary, changes made to the "Properties" field of the ITest does not persist across function calls. Why? How I can make the changes persistent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I looked at the assemble of the ITest and discovered that the "Properties" field is a readonly attribute.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace NUnit.Core
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        TestName TestName
        {
            get;
        }
        string TestType
        {
            get;
        }
        RunState RunState
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string IgnoreReason
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        int TestCount
        {
            get;
        }
        IList Categories
        {
            get;
        }
        string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        IDictionary Properties
        {
            get;
        }
        bool IsSuite
        {
            get;
        }
        ITest Parent
        {
            get;
        }
        IList Tests
        {
            get;
        }
        int CountTestCases(ITestFilter filter);
    }
}
```

Mystery solved!